# IdentitySet in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need a set that uses an identity (`is`) comparison for `add()`, as opposed to a value (`==`) comparison.

For example, I have defined a `Point` class (with immutable x/y) that hooks `__eq__` and `__hash__`. `Point`s compare themselves correctly, and two instances of `Point` with the same x/y value answer `True` to `==` and `False` to `is`. I need to add two such instances to my set, and it's important that the result contain both instances even though their x/y values are the same. Some Smalltalks define IdentitySet for this very purpose.

I'm wondering, for example, if I can patch the built-in set class to include `identityAdd` and `identityRemove` methods. That will probably work, but it seems like a hack.

Is there a better way?

Comment: No, hacking sets won't work, because sets, like dictionaries, use a hash table that *relies* on the `__eq__` and `__hash__` methods. Change the `__eq__` method to *not* compare these two points as equal.

Comment: You might want to use list instead of set. :)

Comment: Don't you want to use a multiset ?

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Is it possible to define a descendant of set -- perhaps "class IdentitySet(set)" that overrides the comparison operators to do identity comparison on its elements?

Comment: @oao: No, a multiset does something different. The context of my application is that I'm creating, storing, and forgetting an object that in turn has multiple sub-objects in the context of an image manipulation task. Among the children are multiple instances of Image, each with its own "extent" field. Since many images have a common extent (640x480, for example), there are many instances of point (one per image) with the same value but different identities. I need to maintain each in my identitySet, but there must be no multiples of the same object.

Answer (score 9):

Here's an implementation based on an `id -> object` map (suggested by [@nmclean](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16994686/4279)) and [`collections.MutableSet`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/collections#collections-abstract-base-classes):

```
from collections import MutableSet

class IdentitySet(MutableSet):
    key = id  # should return a hashable object

    def __init__(self, iterable=()):
        self.map = {} # id -> object
        self |= iterable  # add elements from iterable to the set (union)

    def __len__(self):  # Sized
        return len(self.map)

    def __iter__(self):  # Iterable
        return self.map.itervalues()

    def __contains__(self, x):  # Container
        return self.key(x) in self.map

    def add(self, value):  # MutableSet
        """Add an element."""
        self.map[self.key(value)] = value

    def discard(self, value):  # MutableSet
        """Remove an element.  Do not raise an exception if absent."""
        self.map.pop(self.key(value), None)

    def __repr__(self):
        if not self:
            return '%s()' % (self.__class__.__name__,)
        return '%s(%r)' % (self.__class__.__name__, list(self))
```

Example:

```
a = (1, 2)
print IdentitySet([a, (1, 2), a])
# -> IdentitySet([(1, 2), (1, 2)]) # only one instance of `a`

print s != Set([a, (1, 2), a])  # it might be unequal because new literal
                                # tuple (1, 2) might have a different id
print s | Set([a, (1, 2), a])
# -> IdentitySet([(1, 2), (1, 2), (1, 2)]) # `a` plus two tuples from literals
```

`MutableSet` automatically provides methods: `clear`, `pop`, `remove`, `__ior__`, `__iand__`, `__ixor__`, `__isub__`, `__le__`, `__lt__`, `__eq__`, `__ne__`, `__gt__`, `__ge__`, `__and__`, `__or__`, `__sub__`, `__xor__`, and `isdisjoint`.

Here, unlike in `set`-based implementations, compound operations always use overridden basic methods e.g., `|` (`self.__or__()`, union) is implemented in terms of `self.add()` and therefore it provides correct for `IdentitySet` semantics.

Comment: This is looking good, I'll try out both this approach and also @tom's. I appreciate the effort all of you are putting into answering this.

Comment: My initial results confirm that both this and @tom's wrapped item approach seem to work (each passes my unit tests). I've up-rated both answers, and I'm keeping both in my code so that I can compare them if problems come up later. Again, I **really** appreciate the contributions of each of you.

Answer (score 4):

You can wrap the Point objects in something that will compare their identities.

```
class Ref(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.value is other.value

    def __hash__(self):
        return id(self.value)
```

Here is an `IdentitySet` implementation which wraps its elements in `Ref` objects:

```
from collections import MutableSet

class IdentitySet(MutableSet):
    def __init__(self, items = []):
        self.refs = set(map(Ref, items))

    def __contains__(self, elem):
        return Ref(elem) in self.refs

    def __iter__(self):
        return (ref.value for ref in self.refs)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.refs)

    def add(self, elem):
        self.refs.add(Ref(elem))

    def discard(self, elem):
        self.refs.discard(Ref(elem))

    def __repr__(self):
        return "%s(%s)" % (type(self).__name__, list(self))
```

Comment: This appears to work, I'll spend some time with it next week and confirm that. Its an approach that I wouldn't have thought of, and I like that.

Comment: If you use `set` as a base class, you might need to override much more methods otherwise results might be *silently* incorrect if you call the methods e.g., `set.update` might be implemented without `self.add`.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian I see that there are indeed problems with using `set` as the base class. The inherited methods appear to work with other instances of `IdentitySet` but fail with standard `set` objects. There are other issues as well; for example `set(IdentitySet([1, 2, 3]))` produces `set([Ref..., Ref..., Ref...])`, presumably due to an optimization which copies the data directly if the argument is a `set`. I don't think this can be prevented. I will change my code to inherit form `MutableSet` like yours. That looks like the correct approach.

Comment: As I noted in my comment to @J.F. Sebastion above, I've been exercising this approach today and it seems to work fine. It's much improved by the changes you made since originally posting it.

Comment: I'm now leaning towards this approach. A "feature" (using the dictum that a "feature" is a documented bug) of Python is that instances of long (and presumably other immutable numbers) with the same value do not have the same identity. I'll therefore have to special-case instances of long (yuck), and the wrapper makes that more straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I don't know if this is the best approach, but how about a dictionary of id => object? i.e.:

```
def insert_object(obj):
    id_dict[id(obj)] = obj

def contains_object(obj):
    return id_dict.has_key(id(obj))
```

`id` returns the true identity (the memory address), so comparing it is essentially equivalent to `is`.

But, is there really a good reason why you can't just update your eq / hash methods?

**EDIT** - Here's an idea that combines this with @tom's approach of a `set` subclass:

```
class IdentitySet(set):
    def __init__(self, items = []):
        set.__init__(self)
        self._identitydict = {}
        for item in items:
            self.add(item)

    def __contains__(self, elem):
        return set.__contains__(self, id(elem))

    def __iter__(self):
        for identity in set.__iter__(self):
            yield self._identitydict[identity]

    def add(self, elem):
        identity = id(elem)
        set.add(self, identity)
        self._identitydict[identity] = elem

    def discard(self, elem):
        if elem in self:
            self.remove(elem)

    def pop(self):
        return self._identitydict.pop(set.pop(self))

    def remove(self, elem):
        identity = id(elem)
        set.remove(self, identity)
        del self._identitydict[identity]
```

The set contains ids, and the ids are duplicated as dictionary keys which are mapped to the objects. It's essentially the same approach except that @tom is wrapping the input in a `Ref` and using `id` as the `Ref`'s hash, whereas I'm just directly wrapping the input in `id`. It may be more efficient without the intermediate class.

Comment: Points need to support value comparisons so that they conveniently participate in the kind of arithmetic common to image manipulation. Value really *is* different from identity. I want to compare @tom's approach with extending set and overriding its protocol.

Comment: I don't see a practical way to directly hook set methods to support identity comparison when adding and removing elements. I'll pursue @tom's approach. More to come.

Comment: I actually wasn't suggesting you use this to help modify `set`, I meant you could use the dictionary *instead of* a set. Anyway, see the edit above.

Comment: Some suggestions: **(1)** Move `_identitydict = {}` to `__init__` (currently it's a class variable shared across all instances). **(2)** In `discard`, use `elem in self` instead of `id(elem) in self`. **(3)** Many of the inherited methods (e.g `copy`, `union`, `clear`) are broken and need to be overridden.

Comment: @tom Basing `__iter__` on the base `set.__iter__` instead of `dict.itervalues` seems to have fixed `clear`. I'm not sure what to do about the others. Yours has a similar issue with `union`, and both break when calling `union` from another set i.e. `{1, 2}.union(IdentitySet([3, 4]))`. It seems even though we're overriding `__iter__` it's looking directly at the internal collection to build the union...

Comment: @nmclean I should have inherited from `MutableSet` (like J.F. Sebastian) rather than `set`. The build-in methods of `set` do not use the methods we are overriding.