# Python automatically simplifies floats to ints during set construction

Tags: python

I'm having some trouble creating sets of `float` and `int` data types, such as

`my_set = {1.00 1}`

I would think of this as a set of two distinct elements, a float `1.00` and an int `1`. However, it defaults to:

`>>> my_set 
 = set([1])`

Here, the `float` disappears and only the `int` remains. Things then get confusing since `1.00 in my_set` returns `True.`

I am wondering if anyone can explain what is actually going on? Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> 1 == 1.0
True
>>> hash(1) == hash(1.0)
True
```

Python considers both to be exactly the same value with respect to use in sets and as a mapping key. The only way around this would be to wrap both values in a custom class that evaluates either of the above comparisons as false.

Answer (score 1):

[Hint](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html):

```
>>> a = 1
>>> b = 1.00
>>> a.__hash__()
1
>>> b.__hash__()
1
```

Answer (score 1):

> I would think of this as a set of two distinct elements, a float 1.00 and an int 1.

That is your problem.  Python thinks of them as one element, the number one.  Whether this number is represented as a float or int doesn't change the fact that it is the same number.

Answer (score 1):

> I am wondering if anyone can explain what is actually going on? Is
>   there a way around this?

The explanations given should be sufficient. The simplest way around it that I can see is, if you're getting this input from the user, to not convert it to numeric form before storing it in the set. 
A more complex way would be to store the entry as a tuple of (value, type): `{(1, int), (1, float)}`, but this seems completely insane to me.

I would suggest you think long and hard before making a distinction between two numbers which are equal, based on the form of the representation that the user provides.

Answer (score 1):

As other answers have explained, since (int)1 and (float)1.0 have the same hash *and* test as equals, they are the same thing, as far as the Set is concerned.

Sometimes a language/standard-library will have an `IdentitySet` class for collecting exact objects (by 'identity') rather than equality.

An answer on another question – https://stackoverflow.com/a/16994637/130288 – shows a small `IdentitySet` implementation for Python. It wraps inserted objects in another class, `Ref`, to force identity-comparisons – roughly as Ignacio's answer suggests.

Answer (score 0):

since (int)1 and (float)1.0 have the same hash, you can't get a set which has both 1 and 1.0

you can implement you own set instead. use type() to distinguish between int and float